# How can be able to use conter min length in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I have an `EditText` wrapped in a `TextInputLayout`. The `TextInputLayout` has an option for maximum length. Example below:

```xml
app:counterMaxLength="12"
```

Is it possible to have an option for counterMinLength? For example, if I am entering a password where the length cannot be less than a certain length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think that they are supporting this option at the moment :)

But I think if you want you can easily create a custom Edittext and then validate the minimum number of input field by using

```
edittext.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
                if (edt.getText().toString().trim().length() < 8) {
                    edt.setError("Minimum length exception");
                }
            }
```

or you can you `addTextChangedListener` for your edittext

Something like that. ^^

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it has an attribute like that, because when activity created it has an empty string value which breaks "min length" constraint.

So to resolve that I think you should verify the length in java/kotlin code like:

```
if(editText.getText().toString().length() > MIN_VALUE) {
   // do somthing
}
```